# Neo4j - Group nodes based on relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm getting started with Neo4j and trying to group nodes that have relationships with each other.

The dataset is the following:

```
create (user1 {name:'user1'}), (user2 {name:'user2'}), (user3 {name:'user3'}), (user4 {name:'user4'}), (user5 {name:'user5'}), (user6 {name:'user6'}),
(user1)-[:SHARE_WITH]->(user2),
(user1)-[:SHARE_WITH]->(user3),
(user1)-[:SHARE_WITH]->(user4),
(user2)-[:SHARE_WITH]->(user4),
(user5)-[:SHARE_WITH]->(user6)
```

The result I'm aiming for:

```
group1: [user1, user2, user3, user4]
group2: [user5, user6]
```

The best I've been able to do so far is

```
MATCH (s)-[:SHARE_WITH]->(d) RETURN s.name, collect(d.name)
```

Which returns

```
user1   [user4, user3, user2]
user2   [user4]
user5   [user6]
```

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: what does MATCH (s)-[:SHARE_WITH]-(d) RETURN s.name, collect(d.name) return ?

Comment: @binariedMe, this returns all relationships regardless of direction but the output is not more useful to me. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In graph theory, such subsets of knots are called `Clique`: [`every two distinct vertices in the clique are adjacent`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)). And cypher for finding such subsets is ineffective.

But you can use the procedure [`apoc.algo.cliques`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_graph_algorithms_work_in_progress) from the library of user procedures and functions called [`APOC`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/):

```
CALL apoc.algo.cliques(2) YIELD clique
RETURN EXTRACT(n in clique | n.name)
```

Comment: Thanks @stdob--, this definitely helps. It returns separate cliques for `[user1, user2, user4]` and `[user1, user3]` though. I'll probably be able to use it to get what I want but do you have any other suggestion to aggregate these cliques using only cypher / apoc / ... ?